# Azure Logic App - Loop to write to SharepointList

Tags: azure-logic-apps, power-automate, power-platform

I have a bit of a challenge here!
I receive data from a Form Response trigger as shown in the code below.

I have quite complex flow behind it already, but in the end, I want it to write data to a sharepoint list. The challenge is that it would need to sometimes loop based on the number of answers given in the form response.

For example, when someone replied "Product Company" (as in example) the Input in the Sharepoint should be as follows :

| ReportName | UserRole | FilterValue | User |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PTS - WOL Campaign Report | Product Company | HOP | JaneDo@XXX.com |
| PTS - WOL Campaign Report | Product Company | ITH | JaneDo@XXX.com |

How should I start?? I have no clue.. :/

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
        "Vary": "Accept-Encoding",
        "Content-Length": "493"
    },
    "body": {
        "responder": "JaneDo@XXXcom",
        "submitDate": "1/20/2022 4:32:08 PM",
        "ra22de8ef4d2744f49662d98f618bb614": "",
        "rb6faae7228c4454d91422175db06cfde": "PTS - WOL Campaign Report",
        "rc456e0fddc9440a09a67cbf979173354": "Product Company",
        "rec611b6290ae48179ad62f7d4f0c7a50": "[\"HOP\",\"ITH\"]",
        "r958deb1b0a9c411a8d8a9ccbed256689": "",
        "r80943943042b414c80c3d56b6cb669e8": "Myself",
        "r35825e12ace649ec964d24a86d851762": "Testing"
    }
}
```

Comment: But in the example JSON you’ve given, there is no array, so what are you wanting to loop through? Does that JSON structure ever look different?

Comment: Hi, well.. that is the struggle! 
I think the 2 values to loop are pretty clear right? the 6th value of the body

Comment: Nah, wasn't clear to me but then I had a boys looks.  Does this change ...  "rec611b6290ae48179ad62f7d4f0c7a50" ... response on response?  And by change, I mean, does that GUID change in the response?  I understand the values may differ but I'm keen to know if that key does.

Comment: No that guid will not be changing, just the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ...!  Insert a `Parse JSON` action using your payload to generate the schema.  There's a button there that says **Generate from sample**.

The next action after that should be another `Parse JSON` step with this as the schema ...

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "string"
    }
}
```

... then you want to assign your array property as the content that came from the previous `Parse JSON` action ...

[image: Parse JSON]

Underneath that, define a variable that will hold the individual value from the inner array.

[image: Variable]

... now underneath that, loop through each item in the newly created array.

[image: Loop]

#### Result

This is the end result, the loop traverses over the two objects that were in the sample you provided.

Within that loop, you can get all of your other properties and create as many new list items as the array has items.

##### Item 1

[image: Item 1]

##### Item 2

[image: Item 2]

Comment: My hero ! thanks alot

Comment: @Robin666 "Hero" might be a stretch but you're welcome.  :-)